# how can I style my .ejs file with css?

Tags: javascript, css, ejs

I inserted    in the head of my .ejs file located in views/pages but no result.

styles/style.css is located in project folder.

Any help?? Thx a lot

Comment: please add more code and details...

Comment: Can you please add your `.ejs`, `css` files and folder structure so we can help?

Comment: <html>
 <head>

  <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles/style.css' />
 </head>
 <body >
   <ul>
   <% for(var i=0; i<information.length; i++) {%>
      <li><%= information[i].title %> </li>
      <li><%= information[i].rank %></li>

      <li><%= information[i].user %></li>

      <li><%= information[i].pic %></li>
      <li><%= information[i].score %></li>
      <li><%= information[i].category %></li>
   <% } %>
   </ul>
 </body>
</html>

Comment: body{
  background: green;
  color: red;
}

Comment: thanks a lot,the first would be my index.ejs and the second my css content

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... If your using express.js insert the following code into your server file.

```
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/  PATH TO CSS FOLDER  '))
```

So if your path to your css folder is this
        app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/styles '))

It should work